# What have I missed?

Tags: python, variables, global, local

I'm trying to teach myself Python and am working through some tutorials online. I've created a basic program which asks you to input a name and password (which are stored as variables). It then asks you to re-type them and if they match prints Access Granted.

I've defined some functions with global variables. However if I # out the global declaration my program still seems to work. From what I've read variables not declared as global inside a function should be local.  So with the global declaration # out my program shouldn't work. But it does. What have I missed?

```
import sys

#password = ""
#name = ""
#inputName = ""
#inputPassword = ""
#accountAnswer = ""

def username():
    #global inputName
    print("What is your name?")
    inputName = input()
    while name != inputName:
        print("Sorry, you are not a registered user.")
        print("What is your name?")
        inputName = input()
    #return

def pwrd():
    #global inputPassword
    print("Please enter your password:")
    inputPassword = input()
    while inputPassword != password:
        print("Sorry, incorrect Password:")
        print("Please re-enter your password:")
        inputPassword = input()
        continue
    #return


print("Hi there, would you like to create an account? (y/n)")


while True:
    accountAnswer = input()
    if accountAnswer == "y":
        break
    if accountAnswer == "n":
        break
    print("That was an incorrect response")
    print("Would you like to create an account? (y/n)")


if accountAnswer == "y":
    print("Great! Let's get you set up.")
else:
    print("OK, no worries.")
    sys.exit()

print("Choose a username")
name = input()

print("Now choose a password.")
password = input()

print("let's try logging in.")

username()

pwrd()

print("Access Granted")

print(name, password)
```

Comment: You only need `global` to *write*, not just to read.

Comment: Your `inputPassword` and `inputName` work just fine as local variables. They don't need to be global.

Comment: It works because they are simply not global.... the variables `inputPassword` and `inputName` are local to their functions anyway, and the variable `accountAnswer` is just in the global scope anyways. As to the variables `name` and `password`, commenting them doesn't affect because you define them again in the bottom and call the functions reading them, so they are in fact global.

Comment: There are a couple things going on.  Within a function, if you only read a variable, it will look for a global definition of that variable.  If you write a variable, it will create it locally.  In your case, some of your variables are local.  For the others, such as `password`, it's possible you may be picking up an earlier definition from your session.  To prevent this, try restarting Python.

Comment: As you are new to python, I would suggest trying to avoid using "globals" or "free code" simply ran from a file. I would recommend putting your main code in a `main()` function and use the construct `if __name__ == "__main__":`. And then, what you could do is pass the variables `name` and `password` to the corresponding functions as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you should familiarize yourself with is Scope. You can find a lot of info about it on line but in short scope is where your variable is visible.
So in your example, let's try to follow the steps that interpreter is doing when entering your function.

**username()**

1. Print text
2. Assign value from `input()` to a variable named `inputName`. Note that it doesn't matter if the variable existed before or not. If it didn't the interpreter will create it.
3. Enter `while` loop.
4. Check if a variable named `name` is equal to `inputName`. The interpreter can't see the variable `name` in current *scope*, so it tries to look one lever higher, which is your main script. It finds the variable so it uses that one (which you declared in line 51).

I hope that you understand the main concept here. This however should not be used as your default method. It's better to create functions which take arguments rather than using global variables or higher scope.

One small note at the end. I do recommend you to try using an editor like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/). It will warn you about such situations. It will also help you get better with following code style rules (a document is called PEP8) which include how to name variables, where to put and how many spaces etc. It may sound not needed for now but it will save you a lot of changing habits later.

Good luck!